# What happened to Microsoft Blueprints? And what should I use instead?

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft had this project called [Blueprints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/blueprints) as a replacement for Guidance Automation but then, all of a sudden, it dissappeared. So my question is - what can I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blueprints has been [superseded](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mglehman/archive/2009/05/27/update-on-microsoft-blueprints.aspx) by the [Feature Builder Power Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/67b720f4-9a50-41cb-86a2-82e33b7c5fc4).